# Creating an auto generated table with php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, logic, laravel-blade

I am trying to create an auto generated table which is a part of a project I am trying to do. I am trying to create a duty roster for a group of 14 staff. The shifts are as follows :

Shift 1 : 4 staff
Shift 2: 4 staff
Shift 3: 4 staff
Off duty: 2 staff

To ease this process I have assigned a number to each staff, starting from 1 to 14.

Here is the code so far, but it does not work just right.

```
 <table>
<tr>
    <th>Shift 1</th>
    <th>Shift 2</th>
    <th>Shift 3</th>
    <th>Off</th>
</tr>

@for ($i = 1; $i <= 30 ; $i++)
<tr>
    @for ($j = 1; $j <= 4 ; $j++)
        <th>
            @if ($j==1)
                @for ($h = 1; $h <= 4 ; $h++)
                    {{ $h }},
                @endfor
            @endif

            @if ($j==2)
                @for ($h = 5; $h <= 8 ; $h++)
                    {{ $h }},
                @endfor
            @endif

            @if ($j==3)
                @for ($h = 9; $h <= 12 ; $h++)
                    {{ $h }},
                @endfor
            @endif

            @if ($j==4)
                @for ($h = 13; $h <= 14 ; $h++)
                    {{ $h }},
                @endfor
            @endif

        </th>
    @endfor

</tr>
```

@endfor

The above code gives me a table as below :
[image]

The end goal is to produce something as below :
[image]
Any help much appreciated. :)

Comment: What does not work right?

Comment: Could you show us the result of your current code?

Comment: Sorry guys, I forgot to upload the screens. I have edited the post now to include the screens. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it in PHP and set to Blade only data to display because in blade it's hard to assign variables without modifications or `hack`.

This is what I did:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Shift 1</th>
    <th>Shift 2</th>
    <th>Shift 3</th>
    <th>Off</th>
</tr>

{{-- */$last=1;/* --}}
@for ($i = 1; $i <= 30 ; $i++)
<tr>


    @for ($j = 0; $j < 14 ; ++$j)
      @if ($j %4 == 0)
        <th>
      @endif

        @if ($j + $last > 14)
          {{-- */$last= -$j + 1 ;/* --}}
        @endif
        {{ $j + $last }}
      @if ($j %4 == 3)
        </th>
      @endif

    @endfor

    </th>
{{-- */
    $last=$j + $last -2;
    if ($last > 14) {
        $last = 1;
    }
/* --}}


</tr>
@endfor
```

Output is as in below screen

[image: Output for shifts]